# Jmeter Distributed Testing -vary thread counts between slaves jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am running Jmeter in Distributed Mode. What Jmeter does is- distribute the Number of threads(Users) equally between the slaves. What I want is to distribute it partially. For Eg- Total users- 10, Slave1 - 8, Slave2- 2.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter slaves are totally independent, therefore if you have 10 threads in the thread group 1st slave will execute 10 threads and 2nd slave will execute 10 threads so you will have 20 threads in total.

---

If you want to distribute load between slaves in uneven way you can do it as follows:

1. Define `threads` property in the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

   ```
   ${__P(threads,)}
   ```

   [image: JMeter Threads via Property]
2. On each remote slave set this `threads` property in *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder), like:

   - on slave 1:

     ```
      threads=8
     ```
   - on slave 2:

     ```
      threads=2
     ```

   Alternatively you can pass the property value via [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   - on slave 1:

     ```
     jmeter -Jthreads=8 -s .....
     ```
   - on slave 2:

     ```
     jmeter -Jthreads=2 -s .....
     ```

   See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on setting and overriding JMeter properties.